# Select Parking Lot based on free space in Road Traffic Library of Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I have two ParkingLot namely parkinglot1 and parkinglot2. Please refer to the image below

[image]

I have used a collection namely (parkingSpaces). And in the carSource block I am using the following to select the parkinglot with free space available. Please see image below,

[image]

But this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead do this:

```
findFirst(parkingSpaces,p->p.nFree()>0)
```